# IllegalStateException при загрузке файла клиенту

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

```
protected PrintWriter out;
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
out = response.getWriter();
....
ServletOutputStream outFile = response.getOutputStream();
```

Выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response

Я использую переменную `out` для вывода текста, а переменную `outFile` - для загрузки файла клиенту, 
Если я использую переменную `out` для загрузки файла, то файл загружается некорректно, хотя в JSP такая конструкция работает.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете в рамках одного ответа отдать пользователю и текст, и файл. Чтобы отдать файл, не вызывайте `response.getWriter()` и не пишите ничего пользователю, используйте только `outFile = response.getOutputStream();`. При этом убедитесь, что у вас установлен правильный content-type и правильная кодировка. В текущем виде предполагается, что файл, который вы хотите отдать, — это HTML-файл в кодировке UTF-8. Ещё если вы отдаёте файл, который браузер должен предложить скачать пользователю, разумно добавлять `Content-Disposition`:

```
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename );
```

Здесь `filename` — имя файла, под которым браузер предложит сохранить результат.